# adding links in javadoc to source files on google code

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

I work on an open source project that is hosted on google code.  I'm using ant to create javadocs and I'd like to have links to the source files.  I understand I can use the [`linksource` flag to javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#linksource) to include the source in the resulting html, but this isn't what I really want.  What I'd prefer is to provide a link to the source file in google code's svn browser.  I suppose I could do a simple filter prior to running javadoc, but it'd be even better if I could figure a way to do this right in javadoc.  Ideally, I could have a property in my ant properties file like

```
base.src.url=http://code.google.com/p/myproject/source/browse/branches/1.2
```

and the javadoc command would add a line to each class's html file:

```
<a href="http://code.google.com/p/myproject/source/browse/branches/1.2/[package]/[classname].html">see source on google code</a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard doclet offers no such option, as far as I know. So it looks you either have to

- use an alternative doclet,
- patch the standard doclet,
- preprocess the Java files or
- postprocess the produced HTML.

A feature request to include this in the standard doclet might also be a good idea.